# Grunt-karma:Continue grunt process after test failures in karma

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner

is there a way to continue grunt process after unit test failed in singlerun=true in karma??

```
    karma: {

         unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js'/*,              
                browsers: ['PhantomJS']*/
              },
              //continuous integration mode: run tests once in PhantomJS browser.
        continuous: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: true,                 
                browsers: ['PhantomJS']   
              }

    }

 grunt.registerTask('test', [  
    'karma:continuous' ,     
    'e2e-test'
]);
```

when i run grunt task test, karma test failed and stopped the grunt process to continue.Is there any option in karma to continue the grunt process even after test failed???

Answer (score 2):

Execute `grunt --force` in order to continue executing without validation, I think.